# Max of two columns from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to get a max of the values from two columns from different tables.
eg the max of suburbs from schoolorder and platterorder. platterorder has clientnumbers that links to normalclient, and schoolorder has clientnumbers that links to school.

I have this:

```
SELECT MAX (NC.SUBURB) AS SUBURB
FROM normalClient NC
WHERE NC.CLIENTNO IN
(SELECT PO.CLIENTNO
FROM platterOrder PO
WHERE NC.CLIENTNO = PO.CLIENTNO)
GROUP BY NC.SUBURB
UNION
SELECT MAX (S.SUBURB) AS SCHOOLSUBURB
FROM school S
WHERE S.CLIENTNO IN
(SELECT S.CLIENTNO
FROM schoolOrder SO
WHERE S.CLIENTNO = SO.CLIENTNO)
GROUP BY S.SUBURB)
```

However that gets the max from platter order and joins it with the max of school. what I need is the max of both of them together.

=================================================

sorry for making this so confusing!

the output should only be one row.
it should be the suburb where the maxmimum orders have come from for both normal client and school clients. the orders are listed in platter order for normal clients, and school order for school clients. so it's the maximum value for two table's that don't have a direct relation.

hope that clears it up a bit !

Comment: Welcome to the wiki, You may send your tables DDL to get a better answer

Comment: Why can't you just use a join instead of a union ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade what exactly do i join by though? im not joining a maxed condition. the easiest i can put it is a need a max of suburb + school suburb. so, something like MAX(suburb + schoolsuburb)

Comment: @M.Heydari sorry, im really new here haha. how would i do that?

Comment: @MaryPleorwer, Actually it's not so clear what you need. you query for max(suburb) but you also group by it... can you update your question and add some sample data and the requested output ? (originaly I thought you could just join the two subqueries from the union (I was assuming they returned only on row each))

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you don't need to use a `GROUP BY` since you're wanting the `MAX` of the field.  I've also changed your syntax to use a `JOIN` instead of `IN`, but the `IN` should work just the same:

```
SELECT MAX (NC.SUBURB) AS SUBURB
FROM normalClient NC
    JOIN platterOrder PO ON NC.ClientNo = PO.ClientNo
UNION
SELECT MAX (S.SUBURB) AS SCHOOLSUBURB
FROM school S
    JOIN schoolOrder SO ON S.CLIENTNO = SO.CLIENTNO
```

Withouth knowing your table structures and seeing sample data, the best way I can recommend getting the `MAX` of results from the `UNION` is to use a `subquery`.  There may be a better way with `JOINs`, but it's difficult to infer from your question:

```
SELECT MAX(Suburb)
FROM (
    SELECT MAX (NC.SUBURB) AS SUBURB
    FROM normalClient NC
        JOIN platterOrder PO ON NC.ClientNo = PO.ClientNo
    UNION
    SELECT MAX (S.SUBURB)
    FROM school S
        JOIN schoolOrder SO ON S.CLIENTNO = SO.CLIENTNO
) T
```

Comment: the second one works! it outputs one suburb, i'll be able to test if that's the actual max suburb tomorrowish. but for now i'm really happy with that, thank you so much!